# Group action on Brauer-Severi varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a Brauer–Severi variety over $k$.

I understood that the automorphism scheme $\mathrm{Aut}_{X/k}=G$ as a group scheme acting on $X$ via $$(m,pr_2):G\times X \rightarrow X\times X$$
(the multiplication morphism), and that this morphism is surjective.

**Questions:**

What about the action of $\mathrm{Aut}_{X/k}(k)$ on $X$?

Is there for example a transitive action of $\mathrm{Aut}_{X/k}(k)$ on the closed points of $X$? If not, what kind of assumption is needed to get this?

Comment: It is clear that there cannot be a transitive action on the closed points in general: the isomorphism class of the residue field, in particular also degree, of a closed point must be preserved.

Comment: I see, but supposing this is the case what can we say?

Comment: So suppose there are closed points x and y such that the residue fields are isomorphis as k-algebras does there exsist an element of Aut_{X/k}(k) mapping x to y?

Comment: @Peter: Have you tried looking at what happens for the simplest non-trivial Brauer-Severi varieties, namely conics which do not contain a rational point?

Comment: Or you could even consider the action on $\mathbb{P}^1$, say over a finite field, and then counting will show that the action is not transitive. 

Comment: For a field extension $L/k$, if you have two $L$-points of $X$, then there is an $L$-point of $\text{Aut}_{X/k}$ sending the first point to the second point.  Why would you expect there to be a $k$-point of $\text{Aut}_{X/k}$ sending the first point to the second point?  

Comment: It's at least close to true though. If you have a division algebra $D$ of degree $n$ and consider the $n$'th symmetric power of the Severi-Brauer variety, then this has a natural open set $U$, containing all the rational points over $F$, and this open set is a moduli of maximal \'etale subalgebras. In particular, since the $F$-points of this will actually also correspond to closed points on the Brauer-Severi variety, any two closed points with isomorphic residue fields of degree $n$ will be conjugate by Noether-Skolem.